# Download artifact after job ends in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have two jobs in my Pipeline, one that creates an Android application apk and saves it in artifacts, and a second one that calls an external API to notify it with the new artifacts.

This is a part of my gitlab-ci.yaml

```
assembleProdRelease:
  stage: prod_release
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleProdRelease
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/

  only:
    - prod

    
updateReleaseMgmt:
  stage: update_release_mgmt
  before_script:
    - ''
  script:
    - JOBNAME=assemble"${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME^}"Release
    - |
     curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT --data '{"download_link": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/v4/projects/30/jobs/artifacts/'$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'/download?job='$JOBNAME'", "access_token": "xxxxxxx", "branch": "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"}' http://xxxxxxxxx/releases
```

When a request is sent to my API and I download the artifacts, it gets the content of the previous pipeline ran, how I can fix and download the artifacts of the current pipeline?

Comment: 1. make sure your stage order is correct, so that your updateReleaseMgmt job runs after the jobs that create the artifacts
2. your updateReleaseMgmt job has no "only" key but your assembleProdRelease has. make sure, that your updateReleaseMgmt job runs only after another job actually has updated the artifacts
3. If you have control over your target server you may send the artifacts directly to your server instead of sending it a link for downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a request to the API inside my pipeline, I triggered a webhook that notifies the API of the pipeline's status (Started, finished, failed, etc.) and I based on that I downloaded the artifact. But I had to add the download URL to my backend code.

Comment: I have similar solution and it seems that when webhook call is happening, there is a good chance (more than 50%), that artifacts, nor trace log, are ready to download.